# Insert spark Dataframe in partitioned hive table without overwrite the data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have one dataframe created from a partition table.

I need to insert this data frame in an already created partitioned hive table without overwriting the previous data.

I use `partitionBy("columnname"),insertInto("hivetable")`
but it give me issue of partitionBy and intsertInto cant use at same time .

Comment: Have you tried using `saveAsTable` instead of `insertInto` ?

Comment: i tried with save as table but it shows table is already present 
and parqute and hive table formate issue arises

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `partitionBy` with the `insertInto` operator. PartitionBy partitions the existing data into multiple hive partitions. The `insertInto` is used to insert data into a predefined partition.

Therefore, You can do something like this

```
spark.range(10)
.withColumn("p1", 'id % 2)
.write
.mode("overwrite")
.partitionBy("p1")
.saveAsTable("partitioned_table")

val insertIntoQ = sql("INSERT INTO TABLE 
partitioned_table PARTITION (p1 = 4) VALUES 41, 42")
```

If you require partitions to be added dynamically then you would need to set the `hive.exec.dynamic.partition`
.

```
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
```

`hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")`

I faced similar problem during data ingestion, I did something like

```
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("colname").saveAsTable("Table")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use insertInto there is no need to add PartitionBy or BucketBy in the code. This should be defined in the table creation request.